How to force GitHub to use the latest version of a workflow file (i.e, the one in the current branch / current PR)?
Is it possible to force GitHub to use the version of a workflow file on the current branch, i.e. in the currently active PR, instead of the previously checked in version in main?
After the initial commit of the workflow to the main branch, GitHub Actions is aware that the workflow exists. But after that, I would like each PR to be judged according to its contents, including any updated workflows, not according to the old workflow in main.
How to do this?

This depends on the trigger; how do you trigger the workflow?

I believe, it takes the file from current branch. So, whatever it is on current branch, should be effective. I don't see how it can use old one from main

I tried both manual triggers and on PR create / changes. In either case, it didn't seem to take until the PR is merged. Oh well. I just merged several times till I got it working.
